# Align multiple equations IEEEeqnarray

Tags: math-mode, equations, ieeetrantools

I am trying to align multiple equations left in a two column environment.
The equal signs are aligned properly, but are more centered in the column, rahter than aligned on the left side of the column. Could one help me out with proper alignment? Please excuse me for the messy third line equation, but since I am using a two column environment I had to break this equation line as well.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn,9pt]{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}


\begin{document}

    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{ll}
    P  &= \sum_{i,j; i<j} \left\{ 4\varepsilon_{ij} \left[ \left( \frac{\epsilon_{ij}}{r_{ij}} \right)^{12} - \left(\frac{\epsilon_{ij}}{r_{ij}} \right)^{6} \right] + \frac{q_{i}q_{j}e^{2}}{r_{ij}} \right\} \nonumber\\
       &+ \sum_{i} k_{b,i} (r_{i} - r_{0,i})^{2} + \sum_{i} k_{\theta,i} (\theta_{i} - \theta_{0,i})^{2}  \nonumber\\
       &+ \sum_{i} \frac{1}{2} \left[ k_{\varsigma_{1},i}(1+cos \varsigma) + k_{\varphi_{2},i}(1+cos \varsigma) + \ldots \right. \nonumber\\
    \left. \quad k_{\varsigma_{3},i}(1+cos \varphi) + k_{\varphi_{4},i}(1+cos \varphi)  \right] 
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help.

John.

Comment: Insert an `&` before the 4th line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use `rCl` for the specification.

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}


\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
P &=& \sum_{\substack{i,j \\ i<j}}
      \biggl\{
        4\varepsilon_{ij} \biggl[
          \left( \frac{\epsilon_{ij}}{r_{ij}} \right)^{\!12} -
          \left(\frac{\epsilon_{ij}}{r_{ij}} \right)^{\!6}
        \biggr]
        + \frac{q_{i}q_{j}e^{2}}{r_{ij}}
      \biggr\}
\nonumber\\
  &+& \sum_{i} k_{b,i} (r_{i} - r_{0,i})^{2} +
      \sum_{i} k_{\theta,i} (\theta_{i} - \theta_{0,i})^{2}
\nonumber\\
  &+& \sum_{i} \frac{1}{2}
      \bigl[ k_{\varsigma_{1},i}(1+\cos \varsigma) +
        k_{\varphi_{2},i}(1+\cos \varsigma)
\nonumber\\
  & &\hphantom{\sum} + k_{\varsigma_{3},i}(1+\cos \varphi) + k_{\varphi_{4},i}(1+\cos \varphi)
     \bigr]
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Points to note:

1. `\substack` under the first summation to save horizontal space and get alignment in the subsequent lines
2. sparing use of `\left` and `\right`, that make oversized fences
3. `\!` in the exponents to the large parentheses
4. `\cos` and not `cos`
5. a phantom in the last line to achieve better spacing

With `align`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
P &= \sum_{\substack{i,j \\ i<j}}
     \biggl\{
       4\varepsilon_{ij} \biggl[
         \left( \frac{\epsilon_{ij}}{r_{ij}} \right)^{\!12} -
         \left(\frac{\epsilon_{ij}}{r_{ij}} \right)^{\!6}
       \biggr]
       + \frac{q_{i}q_{j}e^{2}}{r_{ij}}
     \biggr\}
\nonumber\\
  &+ \sum_{i} k_{b,i} (r_{i} - r_{0,i})^{2} +
     \sum_{i} k_{\theta,i} (\theta_{i} - \theta_{0,i})^{2}
\nonumber\\
  &+ \sum_{i} \frac{1}{2}
     \bigl[ k_{\varsigma_{1},i}(1+\cos \varsigma) +
        k_{\varphi_{2},i}(1+\cos \varsigma)
\nonumber\\
  & \qquad\quad + k_{\varsigma_{3},i}(1+\cos \varphi) + k_{\varphi_{4},i}(1+\cos \varphi)
     \bigr]
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @egreg. Which one is standard? Aligning the + signs with = or the first summation symbol?

Comment: @Imran Since the typesetting is two-column, space has to be used sparingly. In a one-column document I'd probably push to the right the + signs.

Comment: @Imran But in a two-column document the line breaks would be very different

Comment: Thank you. While aligning I face a dilemma in choosing between these two.